# If $y=x\ln(x)$, find $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: derivatives

So $$\frac{dy}{dx}=(x)\left(\frac1x\right)+\ln(x)$$
$$=1+\ln(x).$$
This is one of the types of questions where the answer given may be wrong, but I would like to verify it anyway. The answer given is
$$1-\ln(x).$$

Comment: Have you typed the correct equation for $y$?

Comment: Did you mean $y = x ln x$?

Comment: Question has been edited. It was a typo

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Your book has a sign error:  $$\frac{\partial (x \ln x)}{\partial x} = 1 + \ln x.$$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The OP has said that it is his book's answer

Comment: @Ak19:  And the book is wrong.

Comment: You should really change your book

Comment: All these collective questions are being asked as I have noted down all the questions I have problems with and asked them in bulk.

Answer (score 1):

Apply$$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)g(x))=f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$$

Where $f(x)=x, g(x)=\ln x$

It gives $$(x\ln x)'=1\times\ln x+x\times\frac{1}{x}=1+\ln x$$

Comment: OP knows this. He was misled by the book's answer